# Wild Card in Javascript Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, wildcard

Is there a way to use a wildcard in a javascript bookmarklet?

For example, I have this:

```
javascript:(function(){var b=document.getElementsByName('send');for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++){if(b[j].value.match(/^Send Pattarapim a Thank you gift$/i)){b[j].click();break;}}})()
```

That worked great when the item was for "Pattarapim".  But that "name" will change each time.  Could I do anything to make that JS work regardless of what was in place of Pattarapim?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the regex from

```
/^Send Pattarapim a Thank you gift$/i
```

to

```
/^Send .* a Thank you gift$/i
```

The `.` means "match any character here", and the `*` following it means "match zero or more of the preceding thing". So combined they mean, "match zero or more of any character here." (Or you might use `+` instead of `*`; `+` means "match one or more".) Note that that may be too broad, it depends on the text you'll be processing, but since you're starting with a `^`, that tends to anchor it a bit and it'll probably be fine.

Comment: I would just make that lazy instead of greedy, not that it is likely to make a difference in this case.

Comment: @NullUserException: Yeah, maybe, although since he's anchoring the beginning and end, let's just say it would be a very odd name indeed. :-) @Michael: To make it lazy, just put a `?` after the `*` or `+`.